# Viewing PCA variable loadings using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, spatial-statistics, arcgis-10.7

I am trying to use the PCA function in ArcMap 10.7 (or similar builds). I am accustomed to receiving variable loading scores for each PC in non-GIS statistics. These are the fundamental data that help the analyst interpret how the original variables are weighted on the different components. The txt output in the ArcMap PCA, gives the matrices, the eigenvalues, and the eigenvectors, but no table showing how the original variables relate to each PC.

Is there a way to back calculate the loadings from the information given in the output?

I suppose I could calculate the PC loadings manually with a lot of effort, but I am hoping there is an easier way.

The specific context is that I have a large region with nominal observations. I calculated Kernel Densities for each variable, normalized them to the total kernel density of all points, which resulted in a range of values from 0-1 (basically the proportion of points in each variable to all points per unit area). Before normalization I clipped the 20k density rasters to a 10k buffer to deal with edge effects. I entered the clipped, normalized densities into the PCA. I have the PC bands, no problem.  Visually they seem to conform to some of my expectations, but I cannot explain numerically through weighted loadings which of the original variables are influencing the PCs. The first 3 PCAs explain 90% of variation in the dataset. The idea is to use the PCs as input layers for ISO Cluster analysis.